# How to combine external .swf preloader with actual .swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a .swf that loads an external .swf file which is the game. Is there a way to combine both swfs into one? This is the code in the .swf that loads the external game:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;

var array:Array = new Array ("Loading Bugs..","Everyone hates loading screens..","Lovely day, isn't it?", 
"Want instant updates? Follow us on Twitter!", "A game where you can kill bugs, pretty cool...huh?"); //create an array of possible strings
var randomIndex:int = Math.floor ( Math.random () * array.length ); //generate a random integer between 0 and the length of the array
loading_txt.text = array [ randomIndex ]; //put the random string in your text field
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("insectGame.swf");

var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
myLoader.load(myRequest);

function showProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void 
{

    txtPreloader.text = Math.round((evt.bytesLoaded/evt.bytesTotal)*100) + "%";


    mcPreloaderBar.width = Math.round(evt.bytesLoaded/evt.bytesTotal * 200);    
}

function showLoaded(evt:Event):void 
{
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,showProgress);
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,showLoaded);
    removeChild(txtPreloader);
    removeChild(mcPreloaderBar);
    removeChild(mcPreloaderFrame);
    removeChild(Mosquito);
    removeChild(loading_txt);
    mcPreloaderBar = null;
    mcPreloaderFrame = null;
    txtPreloader = null;
    loading_txt = null;
    addChild(myLoader);
}

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,showProgress);
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,showLoaded);
```

Answer (score 0):

You  might want to implement preloader in the first frame within your main swf file. So you should have the sources of the actual .swf.  If you are using Flash Builder check out mxmlc compiler -frame argument.

The core idea of this approach is that you assign the preloader to be the main class of your application, add 1 more frame to the swf file, and you do not instance your gameClass directly. When the content is fully loaded `(framesLoaded == totalFrames)` you make an instance of your game-class using this code:

```
var gameClass:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName("GameClass"));
if(gameClass)
{
 var app:Object = new gameClass();
 addChildAt(app as Sprite, 0);
}
```

here is helpful link:
http://www.drewing.de/blog/2009/09/23/building-a-preloader-with-actionsscript-3-using-mxmlc-and-the-frame-pragma/